# Two column layout, #navigation on the right, but below #content in html?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 column layout and for SEO reasons I want #navigation div lay below main #content div in HTML.

**The problem is - on some pages I want to hide #navigation, so #content must stretch to 100%, but it doesn`t.**.

Here is the basic code

Page Type 1:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="navigation"></div>
</div>
```

Page Type 2:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrap{
   position:relative;
}
#content{
   margin-right:200px;
}
#navigation{
   width:200px;
   position:absolute;
   right:0px;
   top:0px;
}
```

If your want to play with it:

#### **http://jsfiddle.net/fWrAu/3/**

I fix it up with JS, but users without JS would see that right margin on page type 2.

Comment: and then you want the content div to fill the window? If you set a margin right of 200px then you must change it aswell during the click event

Comment: @Dan No, no. JS there is just for tests. For quick hide #navigation. On SOME pages it will never even exists there.

Comment: So you want to accomplish what your JSFiddle is WITHOUT JS?

Comment: @Dan No, i want solution without JS. Updated the question

Comment: "I want #navigation div **lay below** main #content div" hi I just confusing with that statement you said that **lay below** but in your fiddle `#content` and `#navigation` are in same line? the `#content` is in the left and `#navigation` is in right?

Comment: @jhunlio Hi! Sorry for confusing. Lay below in HTML, not visually.

Comment: ahhh... you main in your `html`, I am right?

Comment: @jhunlio Yeap. Updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in normal page html structure like this:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="conten">CONTENT</div>
    <div id="navigation">NAVIGATION</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#wrap{
    position:relative;
    background-color:red;
    }
    #content{
        margin-right:200px;
        background-color:green;
    }
    #navigation{
        width:200px;
        position:absolute;
        right:0px;
        top:0px;
        background-color:blue; 
    }
    #content, #navigation {
        height:700px;
        font-size:24px;
    }
```

if without the navigation lets say in *"about us page"* html:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="content" class="aboutUs">CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

then add this css:

```
.aboutUs {margin-right:0 !important}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fWrAu/5/)

Comment: I was looking for solution without adding another class. But I think it would be possible only if CSS had rule like:"#navigation < #content{}" or smth like that... Any way, yours work just fine, so THX! I'll use it. One question, why do you use padding insead of margin? Is it important somehow?

Answer (score -1):

Could you set the width of content to 100% and set the z-index above the navigation?

Comment: @user2296706 I could, but this does't solve the problem... Right margin a still there. Once more, my solution is't working. I think it can't be fixed. I look for another one